# axios set default headers dynamically

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to set a header that sent with each request:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': store.state.csrf
};
```

This is only evaluated at the page load. I would like it to be dynamic since the csrf value may change later on. Something like:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': () => store.state.csrf
};
```

However this does not work.

Answer (score 9):

i suggest you to do this in an interceptor before request sent like this :

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers.common = {...config.headers.common, "X-CSRF-TOKEN": () => store.state.csrf}
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    logger.error(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 8):

You can overwrite/extend the defaults at any time:

```
// set defaults...

// do requests...

// overwrite CSRF token
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = store.state.csrf;

// do more requests...
```

Or you can [change the defaults only for a certain instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass dynamic header as argument after request data.

```
     let config = {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': store.state.csrf
     }
     axios.post(url, requestData, config)
```