# Multiple API providers with nuxt-axios and a plugin for default headers

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app with many request to the same API, but also i need to make request to different providers apart of my main API and i don't know how to manage the default headers.

This is my working setup create a plugin to add the headers to all the request like this:

`plugins/axios.js`

```
export default function({ $axios, store, redirect }) {
   $axios.onRequest(config => {
       config.headers.common.Authorization = 'token 123';
       config.headers.common["Custom-header"] = 'blablabla';
 }
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: ["@/plugins/axios"],
    axios: {
        baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    }
}
```

`store.js`

```
async changeKeyVersionOnline({ commit }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.get(
      `users/1`
    );
    return response;
  },
```

This works great for the main API but the problem is i need also to make request to other endpoints of third party service provider and of course the headers should be different.

How can i do that, i read about the proxy option of the `nuxt-axios` package but what i understand is this only changes the request base URL, i cant find how to set different headers to a specific request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020246/axios-set-default-headers-dynamically

Comment: Thanks for your comment @skribe but because im using nuxt-axios package and not the `normal` axios, the `create` function is not available :(

Comment: @RicardoA Did you figure this out?

Comment: @MustafaAlammar Yep, let me publish my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution was based on create some actions in a central store so the `axios requests` are made trough this actions.

`central.js` (Where the axios related actions live)

```
import qs from "qs";

export const state = () => ({
  accessToken: "",
  clientId: 0
});

export const getters = {
  getHeadersWithAuth: state => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + state.accessToken
      }
    };
    return config;
  },
  getHeadersWithAuthClient: state => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + state.accessToken,
        Client: state.clientId
      }
    };
    return config;
  }
};

export const mutations = {};

export const actions = {
  async getWithAuth({ getters }, { path, params }) {
    const config = getters.getHeadersWithAuth;
    config.params = params;
    config.paramsSerializer = function(params) {
      return qs.stringify(params, { encode: false });
    };
    const result = await this.$axios.get(path, config);
    return result;
  },
  async getWithAuthClient({ getters }, { path, params }) {
    const config = getters.getHeadersWithAuthClient;
    config.params = params;
    config.paramsSerializer = function(params) {
      return qs.stringify(params, { encode: false });
    };
    const result = await this.$axios.get(path, config);
    return result;
  },
  async putWithAuthClient({ getters }, { path, body, params }) {
    const config = getters.getHeadersWithAuthClient;
    config.params = params;
    config.paramsSerializer = function(params) {
      return qs.stringify(params, { encode: false });
    };
    const result = await this.$axios.put(path, body, config);
    return result;
  }
};
```

`test.js` Other store which use the custom axios requests

```
async updateProductDetailsAction({ commit, dispatch, state }, productData) {

  const request = {
    path: `endpoints/` + productData.id + `/details`,
    body: {
      length: 123,
      name: 'The product name'
    },
    params: {}
  };
  const result = await dispatch("auth/putWithAuthClient", request, {
    root: true
  });

  await commit("setProductDetails", productData.id);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: had to remove the axios plugin file, added api keys to apiUrl in views, maybe i ll find a working example some day

Comment: Look into "nuxt repository pattern"